# Questions about performance versus code based solutions

Tags: discussion, questions, moderation

I've noticed that there is a reasonable number of questions that are posed in the format "*Does doing X this way perform faster than doing X that way?*". Sometimes these questions are popular, and sometimes these questions attract some [inflammatory comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627820/for-quick-web-animations-javascript-jquery-or-css3/8628058#8628058) or are even closed.

My understanding of the FAQ is that these questions are [perfectly acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions), especially if the question can be answered objectively with comparative references. But I've seen a few questions like this deleted or closed recently. So how should these questions be dealt with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after a bit of of hunting around, I came across this blog post: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

The gist of it is this:

> Questions that are not answerable — discussions, debates,
> opinions — should be closed as subjective. It seems simple enough:
> Fact good; opinion and discussion bad.

But why?

> … eventually the experts (i.e. people who are teaching you stuff) get
> drowned out and you are left with an experience that looks more like
> the magazine rack at a grocery store than a book shelf at Harvard. —
> Robert Scoble

It finishes with:

> **We never claimed that subjective questions were horrible abominations that should never be asked.** We simply choose to forego
> those subjective discussions, as there were dozens upon dozens of
> forums which already catered to them. Our fellow programmers created
> [a sister site specifically for their pent up subjective
> questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If it could have been answered by the user performing a speed test of some kind, it's probably a bad question. There are exceptions to this, however.